Identify this movie with a black blob-like creature breaks out of some sort of chamber
I have this vague memory of a film… could be 50s – 60s, black and white as I recall, possibly British.
The scene that I remember most takes place in some sort of industrial facility, could be like a refinery. There is this large chamber of tar or asphalt-like goo that is undulating. Workers are observing it through glass viewing ports. At one point a pipe or something breaks and the black tar stuff gets all over a man’s face.
Any ideas? Pretty sure it is not the Outer Limits episode "Corpus Earthling"

I am 100% sure someone's already asked this question here before... if I can find it, I'll link it to you

And you're sure it's not the movie The Blob?

The Blob was more like Jell-O... Not tar or asphalt...

Might be Quartermass 2 ... AKA Enemy from Space 1957

Well after looking at the YouTube trailer, I am pretty confident that Enemy from Space (1957) is the movie I was thinking of... Not exactly like I remembered, but all the elements are there...

Awesome that you managed to find it. Please add it as an answer and don't forget to tick it off as correct to "close" this question :)

The movie in question is Quatermass 2 aka Enemy from Space (1957).

Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the correct solution to your problem. You might also want to add some details in which way it matches to the descriptions from the question.
